# Actionscript 3 REPL

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL) (Read-Eval-Print Loop) available anywhere for Actionscript 3?  I could not find anything on google, but it would really come in handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Google harder](http://eval.hurlant.com/demo/). ;)

Answer (score -2):

actionscript3 is a compiled language so is this even possible?

Comment: What does this have to do with the ability to have a REPL?

Comment: I thought that the point of a REPL was to let you enter code at run time and evaluate that code interactivly. In javascript you can use "eval" to compile/run new code like this but no such ability exists in actionscript as the compiler is not available at runtime. Did I miss the point?

Comment: Plenty of compiled languages have REPLs. OCaml, Haskell and Erlang come to mind.

Comment: Ok fair enough. It's clearly possible if the compiler is available at run time which as far as I know it isn't in actionscript. I may be wrong :)

Comment: @John Buton: Hurlant's Eval library packages the Tamarin ESC compiler, providing a means of compiling and eval'ing AS3: http://eval.hurlant.com/

Comment: ... which, as I just realized, is what Thom linked to in his answer.